# не отображаются элементы Listview через кастомный адаптер

Tags: android, listview, adapter

при открытии Activity Bus1 появляются пустые строки списка... когда использую обычный Simple Adapter, то все нормально... появляется заполненный список...

Подозреваю, что неправильно что-то сделал в кастомном адаптере...

Кто что предложит?

```
public class Bus1 extends ListActivity {


public static final String ITEM_ID = "id";
public static final String ITEM_NAME = "name";
public static final String ITEM_CONTROL = "con";
String urlGet = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/get_bus.php";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
ListAdapter adapter;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
TextView viewid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ReadDataFromDB();
}

private void ReadDataFromDB() {
    progressDialog.show();

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlGet,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("stat");

                        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            item.put(ITEM_ID, jobj.getString(ITEM_ID));
                            item.put(ITEM_NAME, jobj.getString(ITEM_NAME));
                            item.put(ITEM_CON, jobj.getString(ITEM_CONTROL));

                            arrayList.add(item);

                        }

                        String[] from = {ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_CON};
                        int[] to = {R.id.item_id, R.id.item_name, R.id.item_con};

                        adapter = new CustomSimpleAdapter(
                                getApplicationContext(), arrayList,
                                R.layout.item_list, from, to){

                        };

                        setListAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jreq);
}
}
```

мой кастомный адаптер

```
public class CustomSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

public CustomSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
                           int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    }
    TextView viewId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
    TextView viewName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView viewControl = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_control);

    viewId.setText(map.get(position));
    viewName.setText(map.get(position));
    viewControl.setText(map.get(position));

    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: Все ли правильно в CustomSimpleAdapter???

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что адаптер трубует наследника Map, а вы ему ArrayList даёте... И да - ListView устарел. Есть RecyclerView;

Comment: У вас в адаптере данные из переменной map назначаются. А она пуста. Странно, что вообще не падает.